# What's the purpose of SIO_RCVALL option of WSAIoctl in raw sockets?

Tags: winsock, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

As I know, If one creates a raw socket (with type of `SOCK_RAW`) and binds it to a network interface, he can receive all the IP traffic on that interface only by using the `recvfrom` function.

But, in many examples for sniffers I saw a call to the winsock's function `WSAIoctl` with control code `SIO_RCVALL` to perform.

So, what's the purpose of that control mode in the mission of sniffing?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610.aspx).  `SIO_RCVALL` is what enables the NIC to be sniffed, and to some extent what level of sniffing is allowed.

Comment: I was already able to sniff without this control mode, but I tried the loopback (127.0.0.1). Is it maybe not necessary in virtual interfaces?

Comment: So, why it's not required when you sniff virtual/loopback interfaces? And, if I will nevertheless add it, what will be different?